# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

**ERROR**

> (node:39756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\elegm\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\animflex\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\elegm\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\animflex\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\elegm\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\animflex\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at C:\Users\elegm\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\animflex\api\routes\auth.js:43:25
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:39756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:39756) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here's my code

````
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (!user) {
            res.status(401).json("Something went wrong!");
        }
        const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password,
            process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        if (originalPassword !== req.body.password) {
            res.status(401).json("Something went wrong!");
        }

        res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
});

module.exports = router;```
````

Comment: `if(originalPassword !== req.body.password) {
 res.status(401).json("Something went wrong!");
}`
write it like this way and see is it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] is an interesting error that is fired up when a server tries to send more than one response to a client.

**Solution**

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if(!user){
      res.status(401).json("Something went wrong!");
    } 
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, 
process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    if(originalPassword !== req.body.password) {  
     res.status(401).json("Something went wrong!"); 
     }

    res.status(200).json(user);
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
 }
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is the proper way to handle the conditions in JS, here you can read more about [error](https://www.codementor.io/@oparaprosper79/understanding-node-error-err_http_headers_sent-117mpk82z8)

Comment: **Fixing the error**
The simple fix for this error is to add javascript return statement to the response being sent from the if conditional to ensure that the request handler function exits(terminate) excuting code with the function once a response has being sent to the client. Yeah, it helped! [link](https://www.codementor.io/@oparaprosper79/understanding-node-error-err_http_headers_sent-117mpk82z8)

Comment: I'm glad it helped and you found a correct resource to read and understand more about the error, happy coding:-)

Comment: Thank you :) Happy coding too!